# IEnumerable to list inside linq query

Tags: linq, ienumerable

I am trying to run this query, where I try to fetch categories and there sub categories

```
studentCont.ContinuumCategories = db.continuumcategorymasters
    .Where(x => x.AssessmentId == assessmentId && x.ContinuumCategory != "other")
    .Select(x => new ContinuumCategory()
    {
        AssessmentId = x.AssessmentId,
        ContinuumCategoryId = x.ContinuumCategoryId,
        NativeAppid = x.NativeAppCategoryId,
        score = 0,
        ContinuumCategoryName = x.ContinuumCategory,
        ContinuumSubCategories = x.continuumsubcategorymasters
            .Select(csc => new ContinuumSubCategory
            {
                ContinuumSubCategoryId = csc.ContinuumSubCategotyId,
                ContinuumSubCategoryName = csc.ContinuumSubCategotyName,
                NativeAppsubid = csc.NativAppSubCategotyId
            })
    })
    .ToList();
```

Currently the field `ContinuumCategory.ContinuumSubCategories` is of type `List` so this query gives me a compile time error that it cannot convert `IEnumerable` to list, ofcourse it cannot.

And as linq does not recognize `ToList` method so I cannot even use that inside my query.

I can solve my problem by changing the type of `ContinuumCategory.ContinuumSubCategories` to `IEnumerable` but I have already used this field in many places where it uses `List.Add` method so I will have to replace all the Add methods to `IEnumerable.Concat`, so this can be tedious.

Is there any workaround to directly get the list of continuum sub categories from linq query only?

**Edit:**

when I use this query(used `ToList()` method inside query for ContinuumSubCategories)

```
studentCont.ContinuumCategories = db.continuumcategorymasters
    .Where(x => x.AssessmentId == assessmentId && x.ContinuumCategory != "other")
    .Select(x => new ContinuumCategory()
    {
        AssessmentId = x.AssessmentId,
        ContinuumCategoryId = x.ContinuumCategoryId,
        NativeAppid = x.NativeAppCategoryId,
        score = 0,
        ContinuumCategoryName = x.ContinuumCategory,
        ContinuumSubCategories = x.continuumsubcategorymasters
            .Select(csc => new ContinuumSubCategory
            {
                ContinuumSubCategoryId = csc.ContinuumSubCategotyId,
                ContinuumSubCategoryName = csc.ContinuumSubCategotyName,
                NativeAppsubid = csc.NativAppSubCategotyId
            }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

I get this exception

```
 LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[BusinessObjects.ContinuumSubCategory] ToList[ContinuumSubCategory]
    (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[BusinessObjects.ContinuumSubCategory])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: _"as linq does not recognize ToList method so I cannot even use that inside my query"_ Why, do you get an exception?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I have edited the question with more information, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `ToList()` on the inner query (the one for `ContinuumSubCategories`)

Split your query into two parts with `ToList()` in-between:

```
studentCont.ContinuumCategories = db.continuumcategorymasters
    .Where(x => x.AssessmentId == assessmentId && x.ContinuumCategory != "other")
    .ToList()  // Fetch all the data from the db
    .Select(x => new ContinuumCategory
    {
        AssessmentId = x.AssessmentId,
        ContinuumCategoryId = x.ContinuumCategoryId,
        NativeAppid = x.NativeAppCategoryId,
        score = 0,
        ContinuumCategoryName = x.ContinuumCategory,
        ContinuumSubCategories = (x.continuumsubcategorymasters
            .Select(csc => new ContinuumSubCategory
            {
                ContinuumSubCategoryId = csc.ContinuumSubCategotyId,
                ContinuumSubCategoryName = csc.ContinuumSubCategotyName,
                NativeAppsubid = csc.NativAppSubCategotyId
            })).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Does it work?

Comment: throws this exception "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." :(

Comment: I was about to post the comment that ToList() got succeeded and saw your comment :)