# Populate List<T> inside of List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hey Im trying to populate my model that its a `List<T>` and inside have `List<T>` but I cant linq doesn't allow me to make a .ToList inside a Linq.

Those are my models

CTIPOCHECKLIST :

```
public class CTIPOCHECKLIST
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ID_DEPTO{ get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPCION { get; set; }
}
```

CTITLE :

```
public class CTITLE
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ID_TIPOCHECKLIST { get; set; }

    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public virtual CTIPOCHECKLIST Tipo_CheckList { get; set; }

    public List<CSUBTITLE> Subtitulos { get; set; }


    TROP.Models.TROPEntities db = new Models.TROPEntities();


    public List<CTITLE> getAll(string codigo, int tipoCheckList)
    {
        List<CTITLE> model = new List<CTITLE>();

        try
        {

            var result = (from a in db.TITLE
                          from t in db.Tipo_CheckList
                          where a.ID_TipoChecklist == t.ID
                          where a.ID_TipoChecklist == tipoCheckList
                          select new CTITLE
                          {
                              Descripcion = a.Descripcion,
                              ID = a.ID,
                              ID_TIPOCHECKLIST = a.ID_TipoChecklist,
                              Tipo_CheckList = new CTIPOCHECKLIST
                              {
                                  DESCRIPCION = t.Descripcion,
                                  ID = t.ID,
                                  ID_DEPTO = t.ID_Depto
                              },

                              Subtitulos = (from s in db.SUBTITLE
                                            where s.ID_TITLE == a.ID
                                            select new CSUBTITLE
                                            {
                                                AMOUNTCK = s.AMOUNT_CK,
                                                DESCRIPCION = s.DESCRIPCION,
                                                ID = s.ID,
                                                ID_IDTITLE = s.ID_TITLE,
                                                NUMERACION = s.NUMERACION,
                                                CHECKLIST = (from ck in db.CHECKLIST
                                                             where ck.ID_SUBTITLE == s.ID
                                                             && ck.CODIGO == codigo
                                                             select new CCHECKLIST
                                                             {
                                                                 CK = ck.CK,
                                                                 CODIGO = ck.CODIGO,
                                                                 ID = ck.ID,
                                                                 ID_IDSUBTITLE = ck.ID_SUBTITLE,
                                                                 USERCRE = ck.USERCRE,
                                                                 USERMOD = ck.USERMOD
                                                             }).FirstOrDefault()


                                            })//here I put ToList
                          }).ToList();


            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
return model;

    }
```

CSUBTITLE :

```
public class CSUBTITLE
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ID_IDTITLE { get; set; }
        public string NUMERACION { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPCION { get; set; }
        public bool AMOUNTCK { get; set; }

        public CTITLE TITLE { get; set; }

        public CCHECKLIST CHECKLIST { get; set; }


    }
```

CCHECKLIST :

```
public class CCHECKLIST
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ID_IDSUBTITLE { get; set; }
    public string CODIGO { get; set; }
    public bool CK { get; set; }
    public string USERCRE { get; set; }
    public string USERMOD { get; set; }

    public CSUBTITLE SUBTITLE { get; set; }

}
```

And my main class is CTITLE that have the method GetAll off type List
and I just want to populate with this query but the Subtitulos property of CTITLE that its a list When I populate it using a type IEnumerable it work, But I dont want it returning IEnumerable  I need List But when I turn the property Subtitle to  List and add .ToList() inside the query LinQ doesnt allow me, I have spend like 3 days trying to solve this problem. I cant figure out.

Comment: Did you really need to post _all_ of that code to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Sorry I'm just tying to other developers understand it better

Comment: This doesn't help to understand better rather it makes everybody to leave this thread! btw follow .Net naming conventions I hate members with all CAPS

Comment: What exactly does a TropEntity look like?  Trying to use your code and see if I can figure out what you may be missing.  At first glance, it would seem that trying to use a single LINQ expression in your situation is not a good idea, but that is just my opinion

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578315/ienumerable-to-list-inside-linq-query , possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213744/linq-querying-list-in-list

Comment: MYGODDATNAMINGISSOBADLYREADABLE; I hope you understand what i want to tell you! Also `C` is not really needed when working with C# ( Only `I` is common ).

Comment: Sorry for my bad .net naming convencion its really a problem that Im facing in my job, and I reamke it here at home, because I have to solve this before tuesday, but Sorry For the bad practice, And thanks you for your criticism.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that you want to execute a Linq-to-objects query operation within a Linq-to-entities operation.

A Linq-to-entities expressions-tree gets translated to SQL and fetches the data from the DB. After that the object get materialzed as .Net objects. Only after this step it is possible to call `.ToList()`

So, this means, you could restructure your query a little bit and delay the `.ToList()` calls:

```
var result = 
   (from a in db.TITLE
    from t in db.Tipo_CheckList
    where a.ID_TipoChecklist == t.ID
    where a.ID_TipoChecklist == tipoCheckList
    let subtitulos =  from s in db.SUBTITLE
                      where s.ID_TITLE == a.ID
                      select new CSUBTITLE {
                            AMOUNTCK = s.AMOUNT_CK,
                            DESCRIPCION = s.DESCRIPCION,
                            ID = s.ID,
                            ID_IDTITLE = s.ID_TITLE,
                            NUMERACION = s.NUMERACION,
                            CHECKLIST = (from ck in db.CHECKLIST
                                         where ck.ID_SUBTITLE == s.ID
                                         && ck.CODIGO == codigo
                                         select new CCHECKLIST
                                         {
                                             CK = ck.CK,
                                             CODIGO = ck.CODIGO,
                                             ID = ck.ID,
                                             ID_IDSUBTITLE = ck.ID_SUBTITLE,
                                             USERCRE = ck.USERCRE,
                                             USERMOD = ck.USERMOD
                                         }).FirstOrDefault()


                        }
    let ctitle = new CTITLE {
                          Descripcion = a.Descripcion,
                          ID = a.ID,
                          ID_TIPOCHECKLIST = a.ID_TipoChecklist,
                          Tipo_CheckList = new CTIPOCHECKLIST
                          {
                              DESCRIPCION = t.Descripcion,
                              ID = t.ID,
                              ID_DEPTO = t.ID_Depto
                          }
                        }
    select new { CTITLE = ctitle, SUBTITULOS = subtitulos }
    )
    .Select(t => t.CTITLE.Subtitulos = t.SUBTITULOS.ToList())
    .Select(t => t.CTITLE)
    .ToList()
```

This could look (modulo some typos and brackets) like the statement above.

Comment: Thanks for your answare but it throw me this error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method [TROP.Controllers.CTITLE,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TROP.Controllers.CSUBTITLE]] Create[CTITLE,IQueryable`1](TROP.Controllers.CTITLE, System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TROP.Controllers.CSUBTITLE])'  method, and this method can not translate

Comment: Oh, sorry. The Tuple-type I used is not supported by the EF-Linq provider. I now used an anonymous type.

Comment: Yes, but I need it to populate a list<CTITLE> not like anonymous type

Comment: Okay, I hoped, you get there on your own. I edited again and added another select statement, which pulls out again the CTITLEs from the anonymous type. Their Subtitulos-property has been populated with a list by the previous Select-statement